# Use Deskshell to create an .exe with a sqlite backend?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, desktop-application, web-sql

So I convert an online php/mysql website to an offline javascript client side website/app. Which works in Google chrome. when I import the database data into the sqlite.

And now I like to make an executable (.exe) and I stumble upon Deskshell. Deskshell file structure:

[image]

And in htdocs folder I have my website/app

[image]

Now this part work as I expected with the sqlite db (...yep I used Web SQL), but when I click TestScanner.desk (see figure 1) the database is not selected used?

In app.js I have the following:

```
var running = deskShell.startApp({
"name": "Test Scanner",
"version": "0.0.1",
"author": "mail@example.com",
"description": "Test scanner",
"licence": "MIT",
"htdocs": "htdocs",
"frontend": "chromium-portable",
    "backend": "none",
    "width": "1024",
    "height": "768",
    "defaultLocation": "index.htm"

});
```

Is there a way I can tell the .desk or compile .desk to use mydb as database???

btw: I am planning to hardcode (copy+paste the db data on the pc that uses the app/website)